# SSRS takes out leading zero if the Customer Ref contains leading zero

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have the following situation of running SSRS report with Report Builder 3.0 (SQL Server 2012).

The data field `CustomerRef` contains Customer Reference No which may have `Cust1234` or `00001234`. I want to retain the `Cust1234` whereas to trim out the leading zero of `00001234` with below expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!CustomerRef.Value.Contains("Cust"), Fields!CustomerRef.Value, CStr(Cint(Fields!CustomerRef.Value)))
```

As a result, Customer Ref No with `00001234` can be changed to `1234`. However, all other `Custxxxx` returns `#Error`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but try this

```
    =IIF(Fields!CustomerRef.Value.Contains("Cust")
        , Fields!CustomerRef.Value
        , CStr(Cint(     
                    IIF(Fields!CustomerRef.Value.Contains("Cust")
                    ,0
                    ,Fields!CustomerRef.Value)
                   )
              )
        )
```

The idea here is that is the field does contain "Cust" then the CINT function sees 0 as the operand rather than the CUst1234 which will fail, even though that but of code will never get executed.

Another option (again untested) is the simpler

```
=IIF(Fields!CustomerRef.Value.Contains("Cust")
     , Fields!CustomerRef.Value
     , CStr(VAL(Fields!CustomerRef.Value))
    )
```

As VAL() will try to turn a string into a value by extracting only the numeric parts of the string, it does not fail when presented with a string as an argument.